# How do I valuate using an if else statement and express validator in my node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to using express to run validation on some following parameters with the help of postman. Right now, postman is not giving me any response as it relate to my code, so I don't even know where the error is coming from. Kindly help me out. The route should accept JSON data containing a rule and data field to validate the rule against.

The following json file should return a success or 200 status code when the value for condition is greater than or equal to  condition_value, I should get a 400 status response or failed when condition is less than or equal to condition_value judging by the parameter below when I input the data type  in postman.

```json
{
    "rule": {
        "field": "missions",
        "condition": "50",
        "condition_value": 30
    },
    "data": {
        "name": "James Holden",
        "crew": "Rocinante",
        "age": 34,
        "position": "Captain",
        "missions": 45
    }
}
```

Here is my validation code with the logic to check if condition is less than or greater than and equal to condition_value to either a 400 response or 200 response.

```js
router.post(
    "/validate_rule",
    (req, res) => {
        const SecondSchema = req.body;
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            throw new HttpError("Please kindly fill empty field", 400);
        } else if (condition !== condition_value) {
            res.status(400).json({
            message:
                "Error, Condition must be greater than or equal to condition_value",
            });
        } else if (condition <= condition_value) {
            res.status(400).json({
            message:
                "Error, Condition must be greater than or equal to condition_values",
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Success",
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had an issue with posting on stack.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I did req and response twice, first is before the validation code and then after again. After correcting this, I am still trying to figure out the logic or if else statement.